# Streaming a const unsigned long to an fstream

Tags: c++, stream

I am replacing some legacy code with std classes and algorithms and am replacing an old file class.

obj has an unsigned long member myUL

```
inline std::fstream& operator <<(std::fstream& rwf, const obj var)
{
    rwf << var.myUL;
    return rwf;
}
```

This does not compile but I am having a brain freeze as to why!  The error message complains that it cannot find an overload "while trying to match the argument list '(std::fstream, unsigned long)'"

I have tried

```
inline std::fstream& operator <<(std::fstream& rwf, const obj var)
{
    unsigned long ul = var.myUL;
    rwf << ul;
    return rwf;
}
```

But this fails as well (I thought that passing through the non const unsigned long might help as const_casting it is invalid).

But fstream has an overload for unsigned longs as I am using it in my test programs.  I am guessing that the issue is to do with the const of the class, however const_casting the clas fails with the message:

> Conversion requires a constructor or user-defined-conversion operator,
>   which can't be used by const_cast or reinterpret_cast

and I would prefer to do this without modifying that class code if at all possible.

In response to the below, very good, answer - I have tried the same and added the #include  line but it did not help.

If I remove the const qualifier in the function it works as expected but I would rather not do this.

Code which shows this issue can be seen on:

[Error in motion ...](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90b0da017bef09f4)

Answer (score 1):

Upon testing the code it gives the error you reported. 
i added `#include <fstream>` and everything worked.

Comment: You had better be joking!

Comment: I used VS 2013 for this , try it for your self in a very small program. Otherwise i would have not posted it.

Comment: Sorry, I was only joking when I posted that comment - I should have included a smiley! :-)  However, I have tried adding that include and the behaviour was not changed.  However, if I remove the cast declaration on the function it works but I would rather solve it properly.  I am using MSDEV 2010, my client has not moved up yet.

Comment: @Stefan i's ok :) , i tested also in GCC and Clang and they all have the same behevior, you can check quickly here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: thanks.  I no longer seem to be able to access that page but I have put an example up which shows the issues I am having.  It is on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90b0da017bef09f4